# Importing itunes music + ipod to ubuntu banshee

Tags: windows, ubuntu, itunes, ipod

So I have a Windows computer with all my music on it synced to my Ipod Nano with iTunes. However, I am in the process of switching completely to Ubuntu, so I was wondering what the steps were to importing your music from one computer to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Banshee can import your iTunes media. Once the songs are imported, just sync and you should be fine

[image]

Comment: After I imported my songs, I got a little "x" next to some of them and they won't play. Any idea why?

Comment: Are they DRM'd ? @codedude

Comment: I'm not sure...How would I find out?

Comment: Were they purchased in iTunes ? If so, when ?